# Transparent crystal-like secretion on my orange tree

Tags: diagnosis, citrus

I have  a young Valencia Orange tree (*citrus senensis*) which is doing great, and growing quite well. However, on one of its recent (small) branches, some sort of transparent secretion appeared in a single, localized spot. (It looks like crystallized sugar. I have added a picture below.)

[image]

I have tried removing it, but it came back. Is it something I should be worried about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a phenomena called [guttation](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Guttation). Plants work by pulling water up from the roots.  In situations where the relative humidity is high you may observe these drops being extruded from leaves or stems.  As the liquid contains various compounds when it dries it can leave a sticky crystal like drop.

Not a problem for your plant, no action required.